# Call member function from constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript's Object Oriented programming (from C++ area).

I want to know the best practice of calling member function from constructor.

Following is a working piece of code: 
Obviously the "initialize" is declared ahead of the invocation "this.initialize();"

```
function Foo() {
    this.initialize = function() {
        alert("initialize");    
    };

    this.hello = function() {
        alert("helloWorld");
        this.initialize();
    };

    this.initialize();  
};
var f = new Foo();
f.hello();
```

If I change the code as following, it will fail at "this.initialize();".

**Question 1** Why is that? Won't the Javascript Engine firstly read in all member function declarations of an object?

```
function Foo() {
    this.initialize();              //failed here
    this.initialize = function() {
        alert("initialize");    
    };

    this.hello = function() {
        alert("helloWorld");
        this.initialize();
    };  
};
var f = new Foo();
f.hello();
```

Then I made the change like this.

The function "initialize" is executed on construction, however, the calling for "this.initialize()" in function "hello" failed.

```
function Foo() {
    this.initialize = function() {
        alert("initialize");    
    }();

    this.hello = function() {
        alert("helloWorld");
        this.initialize();     //failed here
    };
};

var f = new Foo();
f.hello();
```

**Question 2**: is the first piece of code the only way of calling member function from the constructor?

Update:

if I have to define a function before using it, **Question 3**: why following code works?

```
function Foo() {
    this.hello = function() {
        alert("helloWorld");
        this.initialize();
    };
    this.initialize();  
};

Foo.prototype.initialize = function() {
    alert("initialize");
};

var f = new Foo();
f.hello();
```

**Question 4**:
Why following code succeeded? (considering the "future" function is defined after calling)

```
alert("The future says: " + future());

function future() {
  return "We STILL have no flying cars.";
}
```

Comment: You have to define the function before calling it, therefore your 2nd code will not work.  Also, the third (last) will not work because **initialize** isn't a function, because you have `()` at the end, which is a return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a method from constructor :

```
var f = new Foo();

function Foo() {
  this.initialize();              //failed here

};
Foo.prototype.initialize = function() {
    alert("initialize");    
 };
```

Execution Process:

```
1) All functions are created (that are defined at the root)
2) Code is executed in order
3) When Foo is created/constructed it executes the code.  
   It try's to run Initialize() but it doesn't find it,  
   it throws an internal exception that is caught and  
   then creates the Prototype method and executes it.
4) If the Foo.Prototype.initialize line came BEFORE the, 
   "var f = new Foo()" then the initialize function would have existed.
```

This process occurs for every line of execution.

Comment: I know this one works, why is that? literally, isn't the function defined after the spot where it is called?

Comment: The execution order matters, that's why when you defined your Initialize() method inside Foo and then called this.Initialize() it worked.

Comment: What do you mean by "All functions are created"? Did you mean "all member functions are created"？

Comment: root functions like Foo... functions/classes... but only the root.

Comment: I modified the scenario in my answer to demonstrate the execution order.

Comment: Checked the mark. Besides, considering your step 3) and 4), it doesn't matter whether or not we put the Foo.Prototype.initialize BEFORE or AFTER the new Foo, because the step 3) process is hidden from us, correct?

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you are calling `initialize` before it is defined (on the next line).

In the second case, you are assigning the return value of the function (`undefined` in this case) to `this.initialize`, so when you try to invoke it as a function later, you get your error.

You may want to look further into the prototype pattern for making class-like structures - Douglas Crockford wrote a lot of useful stuff on this and it's useful for introductory learning: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html is a good start.

Comment: **+1** I have this stupid case of always commenting the answer, instead of posting the answer

Comment: I usually do the same thing; especially since it's a lot harder to write a good answer on mobile without spending a lot more time...

Answer (score 3):

My answers *inline* (kind of)

*Question 1 Why is that? Won't the Javascript Engine firstly read in all member function declarations of an object?*

No, if they are defined as in your example, they will be executed in order, as the method doesn't exist yet, it will throw.

This way would be a different case (not OO, but to ilustrate):

```
function Foo(){
   initialize();  //This would work
   function initialize(){ ... }  //Parser defines its function first
}
```

In this case, the parser does define the function declarations first, it's a different case.

*The function "initialize" is executed on construction, however, the calling for `this.initialize()` in function "hello" failed.*

```
this.initialize = function() {
    alert("initialize");    
}();   //This executes the function!
```

The problem with the above code is that you're not assigning the function to `this.initialize`, you're assigning the *result of its execution*, in this case `undefined` (because there is no `return` inside the function)

for example, if the code were:

```
this.initialize = function() {
    return 2;
}();
```

then `this.initialize` would be... `2` !! (not a function).

Hope this helps. Cheers